# R converts datetime assignment to numeric [XML]

Tags: r, xml, datetime

I have been trying to create an XML. For doing this i am using [XML](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/XML/XML.pdf) library in R.

```
top = newXMLNode("A")
newXMLnode("Node1",attrs=c(id=123,dt="2017-01-21 00:00:05"),parent=top)
```

This should create an XML as

```
<A>
     <Node1 id="123" dt="2017-01-21 00:00:05"/> 
</A>
```

But what's happenning is instead of storing dt as datetime, R is internally converting it to numeric and i get output as

```
 <Node1 id="123" dt="1485043200"/>
```

I have tried converting it using lubridate's ymd() function, as.posixct(), as.date(). All This keeps the datetime format correct but as soon as i assign it to something this changes to numeric.

```
 > u <- as.POSIXct("2017-01-21 00:00:05",origin="1970-01-01")
 > u
 > "2017-01-21 00:00:05 CST"
 > addAttributes(Node1,xyz=u)
  <Node1 id="123" dt="1485043200" xyz="1485043200"/>
```

Comment: format the datetime as a string before doing the assignment. `strftime(u, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %Z")`

Comment: Kindly go through by my answer. Hope it clears your doubt and works for you!

Comment: [You should take care of this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: @Psidom Awesome. Thanks a lot. I don't know how i missed this.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is very simple, you have done small typos. You used `newXMLnode` instead of `newXMLNode`. Kindly go through following R code snippet:

```
> top = newXMLNode("A")
> newXMLNode("Node1",attrs=c(id=123,dt="2017-01-21  00:00:05"),parent=top)
<Node1 id="123" dt="2017-01-21 00:00:05"/> 
> top
<A>
<Node1 id="123" dt="2017-01-21 00:00:05"/>
</A>
```

Hope it works for you!

Comment: Thanks Saurabh13 for the response. But the issue was occurring during the assignment of datetime object. I should have converted the datetime object to string before assignment. @Psidom pointed it out correctly.